# How to get logging level of a pod given pod-name and namespace name in K8s?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, microk8s

How to i get logging level of a pod given the pod name and Namespace name

if its not possible to get Logging level then please tell me why

Answer (score 1):

With kubectl command you can perform this

```
kubectl logs <pod name> --namespace <namespace> [-c <container name>]
```

The container name is required is you have several container in your pod

In the GUI of GCP, you can do a custom filter like this

```
resource.type="k8s_pod"
resource.labels.location="us-central1-c"
resource.labels.cluster_name="cluster-2"
jsonPayload.involvedObject.namespace="namespace"
jsonPayload.involvedObject.name="pod name"
```

[image]

Comment: i want to know the log level like ERROR, CRITICAL

Comment: Is your logger print the log level in the logs? Do you have an extract of your logs?